# TypeError: dst is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, opencv

I use anaconda2 in python script, but it showed me these error information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
     clip = source.fl_image(lane_detector.run)
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 533, in                                                                fl_image
     return self.fl(lambda gf, t: image_func(gf(t)), apply_to)
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\Clip.py", line 136, in fl
     newclip = self.set_make_frame(lambda t: fun(self.get_frame, t))
  File "<decorator-gen-57>", line 2, in set_make_frame
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 14, in outpl                                                               ace
     f(newclip, *a, **k)
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 694, in                                                                set_make_frame
     self.size = self.get_frame(0).shape[:2][::-1]
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in get_frame
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 89, in wrapp                                                               er
     return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\Clip.py", line 95, in get_frame
     return self.make_frame(t)
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\Clip.py", line 136, in <lambda>
     newclip = self.set_make_frame(lambda t: fun(self.get_frame, t))
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 533, in                                                                <lambda>
     return self.fl(lambda gf, t: image_func(gf(t)), apply_to)

  File "C:\Users\shihaohou\Desktop\lane-line-detection-master\detector.py", line                                                                655, in run
     warped = self.__perspective_transform(preprocessed,pers_mat)
  File "C:\Users\shihaohou\Desktop\lane-line-detection-master\detector.py", line                                                                328, in __perspective_transform
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, mat, img_size, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    TypeError: dst is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

The relative code in detetor.py is :

```
def __perspective_transform(self, img, mat):
    '''
    Method to transform the image
    :param img: the image to be transformed
    :param mat: the perspective matrix
    :return: the transformed image
    '''
    img_size = (img.shape[1], img.shape[0])
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, mat, img_size, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    return warped

if self.ENABLE_LOGS:
        cv2.imwrite('./test/def_' + str(self.processed_frames) + '.jpg', img)

    # undistort the image using the calibrated values
    undistorted = self.__undistort(img,self.mtx, self.dist)

    # pass the distortion corrected image through the threshold pipeline
    preprocessed = self.__prepocess(undistorted)

    if self.ENABLE_LOGS:
        cv2.imwrite('./debug/preprocessed_' + str(self.processed_frames) + '.jpg', img)

    # get the current region of interest and load the perspective and inverse perspective matrix
    src, dest = self.__get_current_roi()
    pers_mat, inv_mat = self.__load_perspective_matrix(src, dest)

    # transform the thresholded image to a bird's eye view
    warped = self.__perspective_transform(preprocessed,pers_mat)
```

I looked the cv2.warpPerspective function,does this error means this function isn't use correctly? Thank you for help!

Comment: The documentation for [warpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue)) shows the "old" style (module `cv`) to have arguments `src`, `dst`, ..., while the `cv2` bindings has arguments `src`, `M`, ... Your syntax looks correct for `cv2`, but the error indicates you may have mixed up the `cv2` and `cv` modules. Check your import statements, and have a look at what `__cv2__` points to.

Comment: @Evert Can you explain it in detail? I didn't understand clearly.

Comment: The error seems to come about as if you would have called `cv.warpPerspective(img, mat, img_size, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)`, since that version takes an argument called `dst` (which is mentioned in the error message). Note the use of the `cv` module instead of `cv2`. So perhaps, somewhere the module names got aliased.

Comment: @Evert opencv module in python is named cv2, how to use cv module instead of cv2 in python script?

Comment: @Evert I edit it again, wish the problem be more clear. I feel it is somewhere inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call it as:

```
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, mat, img_size, flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```